# PHP Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php'

Tags: php

PHP:

```
<div class=shadow-box>
  <h3 class=title style=font-size:20px>
  <?php 
    if($pet["pet_cat"] == 2):
  ?>
  <?php 
    echo $pet["pet_name"];
  ?>
   <?php 
      else:
  ?>
  <?php 
      echo "Please Help me";
   ?>
   <?php endif;
   ?>
   </h3>
   <p class=subtitle>
   <?php 
     if($pet["pet_cat"] == 2):
    ?>
    <?php
       echo $pet["english"];
    ?>
    <?php 
        else:
    ?>
    <?php 
       echo $pet["dog_english"];
     ?>
     <?php 
        endif;
      ?>
      <div class=image>
      <a href=<?php
                  echo base_url();
              ?>index.php/Pet/view/<?php echo $pet["petid"];?> id=listinglink target=_blank><img src=<?php $img = unserialize($pet["img"]); echo base_url();?>assets/img/<?php echo $pet["pet_hidenum"]."/".$img[0]?> class=img-responsive id=centerimg></a></div><div class="clearfix quick-info"><div class=left><p><span class=icon style=font-size:12px><img src=images/location.png alt=""></span><?php echo $pet["reg_postal"].",".$pet["reg_city"].",".$pet["reg_country"]?><?php if($pet["showtel"] == "Yes"):?><p><span class=icon><img src=images/phone.png alt=""></span><?php $mobile_phone_number = unserialize($pet["mobile_phone_number"]); echo $mobile_phone_number[0];?><?php endif;?><?php if($pet["pet_type"] == "Lost"):?><p id=rewardon><span class=icon><img src=images/reward.png alt=""></span>Reward:€ (EUR)</div><?php endif;?><div class=right><p style=margin-top:14px><img src=images/mini_logo.png alt=""style=width:95px><p>37070 Days Ago</div></div></div>
```

Error:

```
Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php'
```

Why is it displaying error Use of undefined constant? I checked twice but I did not find anything wrong in my code. Your help is appreciated...............

Comment: Constructive criticism: Don't jam all your code on one line, especially if you're seeking debugging help.

Comment: This ^^^^^  Maybe some carriage returns and indentation.

Comment: the template notation of php is nice, but here the lack of formatting makes it less readable. try to identify the syntax error by running just parts of the code.

Comment: tried formatting your code. but lots of html closing tags missing. it is very tough :(

Comment: Why do you keep going in and out of the PHP brackets? Just stay in them until you're done. And there's an error on line 15/16 (`<?` on one line, `php` on the next) that a good IDE would highlight.